# Make Lists within a List C#

Tags: c#, list

Using C#, I want to make `arraysNames` and `arraysData` be lists of the previous lists. However, I get this error message:

> Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

```
public string[] traitNames = { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" };
public float[] traitData = { 1, 1, 3 };

public string[] suppliesNames = { "Food", "Iron", "Gold" };
public float[] suppliesData = { 3, 2, 1 };

private List[] arraysNames = { traitNames, suppliesNames };
private List[] arraysData = { traitData, suppliesData };
```

Comment: List are created with <> Brackets.  private List<string> arraysNames = { traitNames, suppliesNames };

Comment: `List` is not a valid type in C#. Did you mean `List<string[]>` and `List<float[]>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `List` is generic class within `System.Collections.Generic` namespace so you need to pass a `Type` when declaring its object

something like this:

```
string[] traitNames = { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" };
float[] traitData = { 1, 1, 3 };

string[] suppliesNames = { "Food", "Iron", "Gold" };
float[] suppliesData = { 3, 2, 1 };

List<string[]> arraysNames = new List<string[]>(){ traitNames, suppliesNames };
List<float[]> arraysData = new List<float[]>(){ traitData, suppliesData };
```

alternatively you can also use a two dimensional array

```
string[][] arraysNames = new string[][]{ traitNames, suppliesNames };
float[][] arraysData = new float[][]{ traitData, suppliesData };
```

if you dont want to pass the `Type`, you can use `ArrayList` instead of `List`

```
ArrayList arraysNames = new ArrayList(){ traitNames, suppliesNames };
ArrayList arraysData = new ArrayList(){ traitData, suppliesData };
```

MSDN link: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netframework-4.8)

PS: ArrayList is not a generic type of collection so you need typecasting when retrieving its elements

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a type for `List<T>` since `T` is a type, just like: string, int, object, string[], int[], object[]...

So, you can try again with:

```
private List<string[]> arraysNames = { traitNames, suppliesNames };
private List<int[]> arraysData = { traitData, suppliesData };
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a list of arrays. This is how you initialize them:

```
private List<string[]> arraysNames =  new List<string[]>()
{ 
    new string[] { "Happiness", "Respect", "Authority" }, 
    new string[] { "Food", "Iron", "Gold" },
};
private List<float[]> arraysData = new List<float[]>()
{ 
    new float[] { 1, 1, 3 },
    new float[] { 3, 2, 1 }
};
```

Of course, the better design would be to create custom types to hold the data

```
public class Trait
{
    public Trait(string name) { this.Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public float Data { get; set; }
}

public class Supplies
{
    public Supplies(string name) { this.Name = name; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public float Data { get; set; }
}
```

and elsewhere in the code

```
private List<Trait> traits = new List<Trait>()
{
    new Trait("Happiness") { Data = 1 },
    new Trait("Respect") { Data = 1 },
    new Trait("Authority") { Data = 3 },
};

private List<Trait> supplies = new List<Supplies>()
{
    new Trait("Food") { Data = 3 },
    new Trait("Iron") { Data = 2 },
    new Trait("Gold") { Data = 1 },
};
```

and even better design improvement would be to use a `Dictionary<string, float>` to hold the data. For example:

```
private Dictionary<string,float> traits = new Dictionary<string,float>()
{
    ["Food"] = 3f,
    ["Iron"] = 2f,
    ["Gold"] = 1f,
}
```

to be used as `float gold = traits["Gold"];`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the type of the List:

This is how you would define a list:

```
private List<string> arraysData = new List<string>();
```

So if you want to have an List of Arrays:

```
List<string[]> arraysNames = new List<string[]>(){ traitNames, suppliesNames };
List<float[]> arraysData = new List<float[]>(){ traitData, suppliesData };
```